# Yii2 - adding external js and css in AssetBundle, showing 404 not found error

Tags: yii2

This is my Assetbundle code.

```
public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/normalize.css',
        'chosen/chosen.css',

    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/classie.js',
    ];
```

when i use this code and am getting view file like this, and also getting
404 not found Error:

```
   > http://site.loc/frontend/web/chosen/chosen.css
   > http://site.loc/frontend/web/css/css/normalize.css
   > http://kometonline.loc/frontend/web/js/classie.js
```

And at the same time site.css working fine. How to rectify this error?

Answer (score 0):

That simply means files don't exist by this path.

Move them to correct path or change paths in asset bundle.

Comment: But the file exist in this location only. Is there any file permission or I want to add some code or what?

Answer (score 0):

It showing 404 because your

```
    $baseUrl = '@web'
```

**is pointing to your root directory**. 
You need to change the paths of your css and js files to

```
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'frontend/web/css/site.css',
        'frontend/web/css/css/normalize.css',
        'frontend/web/chosen/chosen.css',

];
public $js = [
    'http://kometonline.loc/frontend/web/js/classie.js',
];
```

Or you can move your css, js and chosen folder to your root directory and don't change the path.

In my case I created assets folder in the root directory and put css,js and etc folders inside:

```
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [
    'assets/css/main.css',
    'assets/css/custom.css',
    'assets/css/responsive.css',
];
public $js = [
    'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',

];
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',

];
```

If you want to override and use hosted libraries by google and add timestamp to your css and js files add this to your configuration. For

Advanced template **./frontend/config/main.php** in components

Basic template  **./config/web.php** in components

```
  'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'appendTimestamp' => true, //adds timestamp to assets
        'assetMap' => [
            'jquery.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js', //Selecting jquery
        ],
    ],
```

],

More info http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html